Unexpected terraform "forces replacement" for google_artifact_registry_repository resource
I'm trying to add upstream_credentials to a remote repository using google_artifact_registry_repository terraform module.
I can do this via UI with no problem, however, when attempted via terraform, I get this output during terraform plan:
  # google_artifact_registry_repository.container-repositories["docker-hub"] must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "container-repositories" {
      ~ create_time            = "2024-02-22T14:51:41.486080Z" -> (known after apply)
      ~ effective_labels       = {
          - "retention" = "medium" -> null
            # (2 unchanged elements hidden)
        }
      ~ id                     = "projects/someprojectid/locations/somelocation/repositories/docker-hub" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name                   = "docker-hub" -> (known after apply)
      ~ update_time            = "2024-05-29T13:31:28.767297Z" -> (known after apply)
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

      ~ remote_repository_config {
          - disable_upstream_validation = false -> null
            # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)

          ~ upstream_credentials {
              ~ username_password_credentials {
                  ~ password_secret_version = "projects/8888/secrets/gardockerhub/versions/latest" # forces replacement -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
                  # Warning: this attribute value will be marked as sensitive and will not
                  # display in UI output after applying this change. The value is unchanged.
                  ~ username                = (sensitive value)
                }
            }

            # (1 unchanged block hidden)
        }

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }


I was not using any authentication before. Relevant variables.tf part and code look like this:
container-repositories.tf
# STANDARD AND REMOTE REPOSITORIES
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "container-repositories" {
  for_each = { for k, v in var.container_repositories : k => v if v.mode != "VIRTUAL_REPOSITORY" }

  provider      = google
  location      = each.value.location
  repository_id = each.value.repository_id
  description   = each.value.description
  format        = each.value.format
  mode          = each.value.mode
  labels        = each.value.labels

  dynamic "remote_repository_config" {
    for_each = each.value.mode == "REMOTE_REPOSITORY" && can(each.value.remote_repository_config) ? [each.value.remote_repository_config] : []
    content {
      dynamic "docker_repository" {
        for_each = can(remote_repository_config.value.docker_repository) ? [remote_repository_config.value.docker_repository] : []

        content {
          public_repository = can(docker_repository.value.public_repository == "DOCKER_HUB") && !can(docker_repository.value.custom_repository) ? docker_repository.value.public_repository : null

          dynamic "custom_repository" {
            for_each = can(docker_repository.value.custom_repository) && docker_repository.value.custom_repository != null ? [docker_repository.value.custom_repository] : []

            content {
              uri = custom_repository.value.uri
            }
          }
        }
      }
      dynamic "upstream_credentials" {
        for_each = can(remote_repository_config.value.upstream_credentials) && remote_repository_config.value.upstream_credentials != null ? [remote_repository_config.value.upstream_credentials] : []
        content {
          username_password_credentials {
            username                = data.vault_generic_secret.container_secrets[remote_repository_config.value.upstream_credentials].data["username"]
            password_secret_version = google_secret_manager_secret_version.container_secrets_versions[remote_repository_config.value.upstream_credentials].id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  cleanup_policy_dry_run = try(each.value.cleanup_policy_dry_run, null)

  dynamic "cleanup_policies" {
    for_each = length(each.value.cleanup_policies_list) > 0 ? { for policy in each.value.cleanup_policies_list : policy => var.cleanup_policies[policy] } : {}
    content {
      id     = cleanup_policies.value.id
      action = cleanup_policies.value.action.type

      dynamic "condition" {
        for_each = cleanup_policies.value.condition != null ? [cleanup_policies.value.condition] : []
        content {
          older_than = condition.value.olderThan
        }
      }

      dynamic "most_recent_versions" {
        for_each = cleanup_policies.value.mostRecentVersions != null ? [cleanup_policies.value.mostRecentVersions] : []
        content {
          keep_count = most_recent_versions.value.keepCount
        }
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}

container-secrets.tf
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "container_secrets" {
  for_each = { for secret in var.container_secrets : secret.name => secret }

  secret_id = each.key
  replication {
    user_managed {
      dynamic "replicas" {
        for_each = each.value.location
        content {
          location = replicas.value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_iam_member" "member" {
  for_each = { for secret in var.container_secrets : secret.name => secret }

  secret_id = each.key
  role      = "roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor"
  member    = "serviceAccount:service-${data.google_project.my_project.number}@gcp-sa-artifactregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "container_secrets_versions" {
  for_each = { for secret in var.container_secrets : secret.name => secret }

  secret      = google_secret_manager_secret.container_secrets[each.key].id
  secret_data = data.vault_generic_secret.container_secrets[each.key].data["password"]
}

data.tf
data "google_project" "my_project" {
  project_id = var.project
}

variables.tf
...
variable "container_secrets" {
  type = list(object({
    name     = string
    path     = string
    location = list(string)
  }))
  default = [
    {
      name     = "dockerhub"
      path     = "path/gar/remotes/dockerhub"
      location = ["asia-west3"]
    }
  ]
}
...
variable "container_repositories" {
  type = map(object({
    provider      = optional(string)
    location      = optional(string)
    repository_id = optional(string)
    description   = optional(string)
    format        = optional(string)
    mode          = optional(string)
    iam_members   = map(list(string))
    labels        = optional(map(string))
    remote_repository_config = optional(object({
      description = optional(string)
      docker_repository = optional(object({
        custom_repository = optional(object({
          uri = string
        }))
        public_repository = optional(string)
      }))
      upstream_credentials = optional(string)
    }))
    upstream_policies = optional(list(object({
      id         = optional(string)
      repository = optional(string)
      priority   = optional(number)
    })))
    cleanup_policy_dry_run = optional(bool)
    cleanup_policies_list  = optional(list(string))
  }))
  default = {
    "docker-hub" = {
      provider      = "google"
      location      = "europe"
      repository_id = "docker-hub"
      description   = "Proxy for docker-hub"
      format        = "DOCKER"
      mode          = "REMOTE_REPOSITORY"
      labels = {
        "env"   = "prod"
        "scope" = "global"
      }
      iam_members = {
        "roles/artifactregistry.reader" = ["group:readers@somedomain.com"]
      }
      remote_repository_config = {
        description = "Remote repository for Docker hub"
        docker_repository = {
          public_repository = "DOCKER_HUB"
        }
        upstream_credentials = "dockerhub"
      }
      cleanup_policy_dry_run = false
      cleanup_policies_list  = ["policy 1", "policy 2"]
    }

Is it something I'm not handling correctly or is it a limitation of terraform that can't update a field that has no problem being added/updated via the Google Artifact Registry UI?
Thank you

Could it be the provider version was updated? What you could do is define it and set it to false and see if it forces recreation, i.e, add disable_upstream_validation = false in your code.

Only change done was adding the "upstream_credentials = "dockerhub" line and the secret itself. Provider was (recently) updated, which is when I included the code for controlling authentication for 3rd party remote repos (new feature).
I tried your suggestion with the cleanup_policy_dry_run to true, no recreation is attempted if that's the only change.
